# Avoid auto-formatting source file on git commit

Tags: html, git, formatting

I'm experiencing something strange when I (git) commit an html Angular template.
I have this code:

```
<button
    [disabled]="votingListService.loadingService.keys['loaderId:' + voting.id]"
    (click)="downloadResourceFiles(voting)">
    Download
</button>
<img
    *ngIf="votingListService.loadingService.keys['loaderId:' + voting.id]"
    src="assets/images/loading.gif"
/>
```

After I commit this file, my file is automatically formatted like this:

```
<button
    [disabled]="
        votingListService.loadingService.keys['loaderId:' + voting.id]
    "
    (click)="downloadResourceFiles(voting)"
>
    Download
</button>
<img
    *ngIf="
        votingListService.loadingService.keys['loaderId:' + voting.id]
    "
    src="assets/images/loading.gif"
/>
```

As you can see, there are some changes (new lines) in my code. No matter if I commit with SourceTree, Tortoise Git or git command line, the file is formatted and if I change manually my file again as before the commit, when I do a new commit the file is formatted again. Something even stranger is that the new commits have no modified files!, the list is empty.
I've been researching about some pre-formatting rules or something similar in git but no luck...
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Looks your repo has some kind of git pre-commit hooks installed. Checkout https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks and see if you have any hook installed

Comment: @GAGANDEEPSINGH. I see in .git/hooks a lot of scripts which all point to husky.sh, it seems it's a tool to manage git hooks (but I didn't install it). Please, consider writing your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Husky does not come with Git, nor with your computer, so you did install it—though perhaps not by anything you remember running, and perhaps not by a direct "please install husky now" command. That is, you probably ran an "install some software for me" without looking at *what* this command actually *did* install, and one of the things it did install was husky.

Comment: This sort of thing is why you should never just run "install some software for me" commands. Always *understand* **what** you're installing, and why.

Comment: @torek, I never ran an "install some software for me", although honestly, I have no idea how that hook was installed, but thanks for your advice ;)

Comment: How did you install Angular?

Comment: @torek That's a very good question, but I don't remember :). However, I found how Husky was installed! The clue was that the husky.local.sh file had this: packageManager=npm
cd "WebApp/Client/ngx-datatable-master/" and I have this component installed in my project. but the component installation is not installing Husky. I downloaded the whole ngx-datatable project inside my repo and run "npm i" This is the cause, the husky script was copied again to my .git/hooks folder surely cause ngx-datatable includes it. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering because the usual Angular install *doesn't* install husky, but does use npm. I suspect there are packaged distributions of Angular that *do* install husky via npm, while also installing Angular. If so, that would perhaps have been the source of this. A lot of people seem to be having husky hooks installed in their Git systems, without explicitly asking for them, so it would be nice to know about some of the sources...

Comment: In this case, it must be ngx-database doing it (I gather).

Comment: yeah, you're right. ngx-dtatable has "husky": "^4.2.4".   "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  }
 in its package.json project. It doesn't install husky with the npm package but it installs husky with the ngx-datatable project. Hope this helps.

Comment: @LeonardoX  bk2204 has already written a detailed answer so I don't think I need to add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the case that you have some sort of hook installed which is causing things to be automatically formatted.  First, look to see if you have `core.hookspath` set: `git config core.hookspath`.  If so, your hooks are in that directory; otherwise, they'll be in `.git/hooks`.

Look through that directory and look for any `pre-commit` hooks or other hooks with `commit` in the name.  You can inspect them to see what they're doing, and then, if you don't like their behavior, rename them or delete them.

If you don't have any hooks installed, then the likelihood is that your editor is automatically invoking a formatter on save.  How to disable that functionality would be dependent on your editor, and you should read its documentation to determine how to fix it.